# Fetch browser token in python

Tags: python, selenium, browser, access-token

I want to get Auth token from browser, I am using **selenium** to make browser instance. I want to fetch the tokens in the network tab. How do I get it?

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium has a build in method to get all the network details from the browser instance. To use it you have to use 'driver.requests'; this will give you the list of all the network requests the browser instance has made and all the headers the browser has received. If you want token with any name just replace `"name_of_token_you_you_want"` with the name of the token you want in inverted comma.

But, before you get the token, you have to confirm the token exists. This is why I added line 3, to confirm the token exists and then *getting* the token.

If you know what URL the token will have you can have an `and` statement to be sure the token is correct.

You need to change `type_of_method_you_want` to "POST" or "GET", depending on type of token you want.

You also have to change `request_url_you_want` to a URL your token will send or receive to or from.

```
for request in driver.requests:
    if request.method == "type_of_method_you_want" and request.url == "request_url_you_want":
        if request.headers.get("name_of_token_you_want"): #to confirm it exists before assigning a variable to it.
            token = request.headers.get("name_of_token_you_want")
            print(token)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.